# How to restart GPU without reboot (softreset)?

Tags: ati, gpu

How do I restart the GPU from command line?

Using a HP DV6 laptop with Ubuntu 12.04-64 and an ATI mobile GPU. Installed the standard ATI propriety drivers suggested by Ubuntu. When I close the lid, the computer goes down to suspend mode. When open the lid, everything but the screen resumes again. Just black. I'll guess I have to put a GPU reset script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`. But how do I restart/reset the GPU?

Comment: Your best bet would be using the scripts that control sleep and resume. You could do it theoretically by unloading the kernel module for fglrx and then loading it again (using `rmmod` and `modprobe`), but it would be kind of impossible with nothing on the screen (unless you ssh in) ;)

Answer (score 19):

Run one of the next commands in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) or, better, in TTY# using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd>, where `#` is a number from 1 to 6:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart
```

or

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

This will restart the graphics environment.

I don't know *yet* from what reason, but these commands worked for me only in TTY. Anyway, if you are stuck in a black screen after you are running one of these commands in terminal, just go in TTY and run next command:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM:

> LightDM is the default display manager for Ubuntu, Edubuntu, Xubuntu
>   and Mythbuntu since 11.10 release, for Lubuntu since 12.04 release,
>   and for Kubuntu beginning with 12.10.

So, restarting LightDM entail restarting the GDM without rebooting the machine

Comment: Isn't lightdm only responsible for the login screen?

Comment: @papukaija Not only/really; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Radu.

But restarting the lightdm seems to reset the whole desktop and all programs and open windows are lost.
I was thinking about a way just to reset the GPU after the laptop lid was opened and the computer comes out of sleep mode.
How would I do that?

Comment: @LapBuntu You will not find another way to restart GDM. Anyway, by restarting GPU is not the good way to fix your problem. Maybe [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162078/147044) will provide you a good solution for your problem.

Comment: Still investigating this and will get back.

Comment: careful, all your programs will be closed instantly.

Answer (score 4):

Try if switching back and forth from the graphic screen to a virtual tty works. I mean, when you have the black screen, try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and, if and when you have the login screen, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. If the graphic screen doesn't come back, stop reading...

If the screen comes back you can try to add this to your sleep scripts (kudos to the forum entry http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290:)

```
#!/bin/sh
# 

case "${1}" in
        hibernate|suspend)

        chvt 1 
        ;;
        resume|thaw)

        chvt 7
        ;;
esac
```

Put this script in a file in your `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` directory, for example `99_vthack`, and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_vthack
```

The `99_` means that this script is run at the end of the resume sequence.

This hack seems to work in a series of AMD-based laptops. YMMV...

Answer (score 1):

After installing [this package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptechocolor/files/Ubuntu%20.deb%20packages/scriptechocolor_20160511-212922_all.deb/download), you should be able to use [this script](https://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/ac93a3229405e160db2d6ecf331e3bb8bac77aa7/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secFixScreen.sh) to resolve your issue. I am using a Dell Vostro 1000.

As the screen is messed, you will have to bind a key to start this script, I suggest <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Also, for each try fix step, it will speak what it is doing, so you will know what is happening. When the screen gets fixed, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the script (it should be started using `xterm` to be interactive).

What it does is basically change between all possible screen resolutions, and may also open a new X session to try to force the workaround to work.

It wont work if the screen is locked though, so you will have at least to blind login.. OR maybe if run on the text console vt 1, with `DISPLAY=:0`, may do the trick too.