# Wake from suspend results in odd visual errors

Tags: suspend

I'm on an Asus laptop running 16.04.  Lately, after I close the lid (set to suspend on close lid), I am intermittently getting very odd artifacts across the screen.  Essentially, most icons are missing, moved, or misplaced.  In addition, almost all text is missing or chopped in most (but not all) applications, including the Unity GUI.

Below are two pics:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

**Any idea what be creating these visual errors?**  It can be recovered through a log out or restart.  But I can't see the words in the menu bar.

Comment: Best guess as to cause is the driver not properly handling suspend. Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/311050/how-to-restart-gpu-without-reboot-softreset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer -- but it randomly stopped happening.  Maybe a kernel update or some other update cured it.